# kotlin cargar grafico - groupby

Tags: kotlin, group-by, graph

Tengo una lista de la cual obtengo unas empresas y un tiempo en minutos.
El caso es que quiero agrupar las empresas, que me muestre la suma de los minutos de cada una, y mostrarlo en un grafico de barras.
El caso es que el grafico no me muestra nada, sale completamente vacío.
Aquí mi código:

```
class MainBar : AppCompatActivity() {
    var itemsAgenda: ArrayList<ResultsAgenda> = ArrayList()
    lateinit var barChart: BarChart
    lateinit var barData: BarData
    lateinit var barDataSet: BarDataSet
    var barEntries : ArrayList<BarEntry> = ArrayList()

    data class Persona (var nombre: String, var tiempoAcumulado: Int)

    private var personas: MutableList<Persona> = arrayListOf()
    private var totalMinutos: Int = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grafic)
        barChart = findViewById(R.id.idBarChart)

        getData()
        getGraphic()
    }

    private fun getGraphic() {
        getDatos(itemsAgenda)
        barDataSet = BarDataSet(barEntries, "Approved Store")

        barData = BarData(barDataSet)
        barChart.data = barData
        barDataSet.valueTextColor = Color.BLACK
        barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS, 250)
        barDataSet.valueTextSize = 16f
        barChart.description.isEnabled = true
    }

    private fun getData() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val call = ApiClient.client!!.create(APIService::class.java).getAgenda().execute()
            val clientes = call.body()

            runOnUiThread {
                getDatos(clientes!!.resultsAgenda)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getDatos(agenda : List<ResultsAgenda>) {

        itemsAgenda = agenda as ArrayList<ResultsAgenda>

        for (res in agenda){
            if (res.total_time.isNotBlank() ){

                val localTime = LocalTime.parse(res.total_time)
                val duration : Duration = Duration.between(LocalTime.MIN, localTime)
                val minutos = duration.toMinutes().toInt()
                totalMinutos = minutos
                personas.add(Persona(res.empresa, minutos))

                val groupHours = personas
                    .groupingBy(Persona::nombre)
                    .fold(0) { sum, res -> sum + res.tiempoAcumulado }

                groupHours.forEach { (nombre, tiempo) ->
                    tiempo.toFloat()

                    for (res in 1..5){
                        barEntries.add(BarEntry(res.toFloat(), tiempo.toFloat()))

                        println("GetDatos: $res - $tiempo")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que el problema principal es que estás agregando entradas al gráfico de barras dentro del bucle forEach, lo que provoca que las entradas se repitan. Además, estás usando un índice "res" en lugar de un índice único para cada empresa. Intenta mover la creación de las entradas del gráfico de barras fuera del bucle y usar un índice único. Aquí tienes una versión modificada de tu función `getDatos`:

```kotlin
private fun getDatos(agenda: List<ResultsAgenda>) {
    itemsAgenda = agenda as ArrayList<ResultsAgenda>

    for (res in agenda) {
        if (res.total_time.isNotBlank()) {

            val localTime = LocalTime.parse(res.total_time)
            val duration: Duration = Duration.between(LocalTime.MIN, localTime)
            val minutos = duration.toMinutes().toInt()
            totalMinutos = minutos
            personas.add(Persona(res.empresa, minutos))
        }
    }

    val groupHours = personas
        .groupingBy(Persona::nombre)
        .fold(0) { sum, res -> sum + res.tiempoAcumulado }

    var index = 0
    groupHours.forEach { (nombre, tiempo) ->
        barEntries.add(BarEntry(index.toFloat(), tiempo.toFloat()))
        println("GetDatos: $nombre - $tiempo")
        index++
    }
}
```

**Edición:**
Si eso no funciona, podrías probar actualizar el gráfico después de que los datos estén listos. Aquí te dejo el codigo:

1. Elimina la llamada a `getGraphic()` en `onCreate()`.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grafic)
    barChart = findViewById(R.id.idBarChart)

    getData()
}
```

2. Llama a `getGraphic()` después de que los datos estén listos en `getData()`.

```kotlin
private fun getData() {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val call = ApiClient.client!!.create(APIService::class.java).getAgenda().execute()
        val clientes = call.body()

        runOnUiThread {
            getDatos(clientes!!.resultsAgenda)
            getGraphic() // Llama a getGraphic() aquí.
        }
    }
}
```

3. Elimina la llamada a `getDatos()` en `getGraphic()`.

```kotlin
private fun getGraphic() {
    // getDatos(itemsAgenda) // Elimina esta línea.
    barDataSet = BarDataSet(barEntries, "Approved Store")

    barData = BarData(barDataSet)
    barChart.data = barData
    barDataSet.valueTextColor = Color.BLACK
    barDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS, 250)
    barDataSet.valueTextSize = 16f
    barChart.description.isEnabled = true
}
```

Podrías probar con esta alternativa. Espero que te funcione...

Comment: sigue sin mostrar nada

Comment: He editado la respuesta, prueba con lo que te he dejado arriba.

Comment: no chart data avaliable

Comment: Revisaste los registros de errores en Logcat para obtener más información sobre el problema?

Comment: Perfecto casi, hay que tocar el grafico para que cargue los datos